# Can't change the code to list comprehension

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension, slice

My question is kind of simple yet I don't seem to find the answer.

I have the following line in my code that works fine:

```
Uniquesample = np.matrix([[   1.   ,    0.   ],
                   [   2.   , -106.965],
                   [   3.   ,  -83.835],
                   [   4.   ,   12.5  ],
                   [   5.   , -141.6  ],
                   [   6.   ,  -17.25 ],
                   [   7.   ,  -94.785],
                   [   8.   ,  -26.785],
                   [   9.   , -125.835],
                   [  10.   ,    6.865],
                   [  11.   ,   16.23 ],
                   [  12.   ,   61.45 ],
                   [  13.   ,   42.625],
                   [  14.   , -163.655],
                   [  15.   , -116.3  ],
                   [  16.   ,   15.82 ],
                   [  17.   , -166.055],
                   [  18.   ,   90.025],
                   [  19.   ,   14.215],
                   [  20.   ,   82.465]])
L, W = Uniquesample.shape
ModelNumber = 8
Members = np.zeros((L,ModelNumber*W))

seq=[4, 7, 9, 2, 15, 16, 19]
i=0
Count = [7]
for j in seq:
    Members[:Count[i]:,W*i:W*(i+1)] = Uniquesample[j]
```

Ps: Uniquesample is a 800 x 2 matrix, so i only put the first 20 rows here for simplicity.
I tried to change the for loop to another format using "list comprehension":

```
Members[:Count[i]:,W*i:W*(i+1)] = [Uniquesample[j] for j in seq]
```

But it does not work. I get the following error: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array would exceed the maximum number of dimension of 2."

The thing is. Did I "translate" the code correctly to the list comprehension format?

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you show us a snippet / demo what ```Members / UniqueSample``` is in order to understand what you want to do?

Comment: Can you provide some more context around what is in `seq`, `Uniquesample`, and `Members`? I think `Uniquesample` is a list and with `j` you are trying to access the index?

Comment: `:Count[i]:` is just an obfuscated way of slicing `:Count[i]`, right? Is that a base Python array.array, numpy.ndarray, pandas DataFrame? (EDIT: you clarified it's an np.matrix)

Comment: Hey guys, I have updated the question with more information about the code. Sorry it was missing before.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I used `seq=[4, 7, 9, 2, 15, 16, 19]`, and replaced the for-loop with the list comprehension statement... and it could run without error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `seq=[4, 7, 9, 2, 15, 16, 19]` in below example. The initial `Members` array looks like this:
[image]

In the for-loop, `Members[:Count[i]:,W*i:W*(i+1)] = Uniquesample[j]` will replace those 7x2 elements (in red) with the final value in for-loop.

[image]

However the list comprehension `Members[:Count[i]:,W*i:W*(i+1)] = [Uniquesample[j] for j in seq]` will assign each element differently.

[image]

FYI, I'm using numpy version '1.18.5', so it may not run properly on `www.onlinegdb.com` because of old numpy version.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that! I changed seq to `seq=[4, 7, 9, 2, 15, 16, 19]` like you did but still got the same error from before. I am using Anaconda with Spyder's latest version. I changed the code in the question to help with reproducibility. The strange is that I uploaded the files and run them in Google Colab and it worked. What could be happening? Is Spyder in any way refusing to compute the list comprehension?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Spyder (fresh start), and run the codes again?

Comment: Yes, I actually uninstalled Anaconda and Spyder and reinstalled them again, but the code is still now working. I also tried the code in this online compiler and it shows the error as well. Could you give it a look? https://onlinegdb.com/dy0F2qXrJ

Comment: Yes very strange. I copied the online codes from `onlinegdb` and could run successfully on my local machine, using Python 3.8.3 and numpy '1.18.5'. Can you check the other IDE using `!python --version` and `np.version.version`

Comment: Spyder's python version is 3.8.10 and numpy is 1.20.2. Google Colab's is 3.7.10 and 1.19.5. I think I will try to downgrade my python version to 3.8.3 like yours and try to run it

Comment: I downgraded numpy to version 1.18.5 like yours and now it runs without erros in Spyder. There is something in newer numpy versions that identifies this list comprehension structure as an error

Comment: interesting findings! So versions do matter in complex codes! I'm glad we found the root cause

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Black Raven. I "lost" three days trying to fix this error.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

The point is, in first code you are assigning one item of Uniquesample[j] each time in Members[:Count[i]:,W*i:W*(i+1)]. First Uniquesample[0] to Members[:Count[i]:,W*i:W*(i+1)], then Uniquesample[1] to same Members[:Count[i]:,W*i:W*(i+1)] and so on.

In your second code you are trying to put a list of Uniquesample items into a location, which can only hold one item. That's why the error.